# python: pandas.DataFrame，how to avoid keyerror?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

In `C++`, when I can't find a keyword in a table, it will return `NULL` or in database it will return a empty table, so the program continues to run. But in `python`, it throws an `exception`, and interrupts my program. Can I avoid that?
for example, I have such a DataFrame named `datevar` :

```
(datetimeIndex)   value
2001-01-01           1
2001-01-02           1
2001-01-03           3
....

v = datevar.xs('2000-01-01', level='date') # of course "keyError"
v = datevar.loc['2000-01-01' , :]          # of course "keyError"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: how working `datevar['2000-01-01']` ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can check if the index is existed in the df's index or the columns 
before you get the value of that  key.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df
Out[6]: 
  (datetimeIndex)  value
0      2001-01-01      1
1      2001-01-02      1
2      2001-01-03      3
key = "2000-01-01"
if key in df.index:
    v = df.xs('2000-01-01', level='date')  # of course "keyError"
    v = df.loc['2000-01-01', :]  # of course "keyError"
else:
    v = None
v
```

Comment: Like `dict` has `get` method there should be some method which doesn't hurt and halt.